# How to implement autocomplete using ang-jsoneditor (JSON editor in Angular)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8, jsoneditor

I am working on an angular project which uses ang-jsoneditor(https://www.npmjs.com/package/ang-jsoneditor) for JSON.

```
"ang-jsoneditor": "^1.8.4"
"jsoneditor": "^8.6.8"
```

ang-jsoneditor internally uses **jsoneditor** (https://github.com/josdejong/jsoneditor/blob/master/docs/api.md).

autocomplete is an existing option in core jsoneditor even it provides example on usage.

I could not see similar option in ang-jsoneditor.

**JsonEditorOptions** and **JsonEditorComponent** both do not show support for autocomplete feature.

Can anyone please point me in a direction if possible. I could not find any hope on google.

Comment: Have you got any solution for it? I am trying to use this feature in Angular 6.

Comment: Also looking for solution to this